# Append href attribute in hyperlinks with URL in PHP and DOM

Tags: php, dom, hyperlink

I'm using DOM's `loadHTMLFile` to grab a page from elsewhere.

I need to find all hyperlinks on the page and then append them so they begin with another, fixed address. E.G.:

Take:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"> Google yay! </a>
```

And turn it into:

```
<a href="http://cheese.com/http://www.google.com"> Google yay! </a>
```

Unsure of how to go about doing this. Many thanks in advance for any help. E-Beer for the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

use `$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')` to get a nodeList. Check if the `->length` is greater than 0. If so, iterate with a `foreach` or `for loop` using the `->length` as the counter and `$nodelist->item($i)`. Grab the `->getAttribute('href')`. If it matches a certain pattern using regex testing, then `$el->setAttribute($newhref);`

Comment: That sounds great but my limited knowledge of DOM means it'll take me at least 7 years to implement. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @DrShamoon the answer is already pointing you into the right direction. You want the codez :)

Comment: Whilst that would save me a lot of time, it's not necessary. I wouldn't know where to begin with the regex and not sure why the length thing exists or how to use it as a counter? The rest i reckon i could probably scramble together.

Comment: You don't actually really need to use regex.. you could though. The length is on the nodelist returned by the first method called.